# SAS Date Functions

Tags: sas

I have a SAS data set where one of the columns named `ISSUE_DATE` is text type and has date values in the format of `'YYYYMMDD'`. I'm writing a query against the this data set and would like to retrieve all rows where `ISSUE_DATE` is  <= today -2 . How can i write the query for this.

```sql
SELECT * FROM WORK.DATASET WHERE ISSUE_DATE <= today()-2.
```

I'm new to SAS and don't know much date functions and conversions. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's probably worth noting that whichever method you use, any missing date values will be returned as they will count as being <=today()-2.  If you want to exclude these then add an extra condition - 'and issue_date is not null'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert the data type to numeric, using the INPUT function and the relevant informat, for SAS to recognise the date. You can do this within the WHERE clause which saves creating an extra column.  So your query will look like :

SELECT * FROM WORK.DATASET WHERE INPUT(ISSUE_DATE,YYMMDD8.) <= today()-2

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Keith's answer, it may be more efficient to do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   WORK.DATASET 
WHERE  ISSUE_DATE <= PUT( today()-2 , YYMMDDN8.)
```

This will save SAS from having to run the INPUT function on each observation.

Comment: I may be stupid here (or just a lack of understanding on how WHERE clauses are optimised), but doesn't your solution run the PUT function on each observation?  I suppose one option is to store the value TODAY-2 in a macro variable and reference that.  I chose to convert to numeric as it is more efficient to match numbers than characters and it is safer to compare dates stored as numbers.  The format specified is the only one that will work (using <=) when stored as a character, without falling foul of cross century dates, so your solution is fine in this instance.

Comment: I think you're missing the `<=` operator in your solution.

Comment: Opps, you are correct.  I should have said to use the YYMMDDN8. format to match the data.  And yes, it should be <=.  I'll fix that as well.

Comment: Also, using the PUT function on the right-side of the WHERE clause should allows SAS to recognize that expression as a constant, such that the PUT function is only executed once, compared to executing the INPUT function for each obs in the data.

Comment: Hello All, Thanks for the answers. This morning there was a change and ISSUE_DATES format was changed to "DDMONYY:HH:MM:SS" , i guess this is datetime20. So i used the following query SELECT * FROM WORK.DATASET WHERE DATEPART(ISSUE_DATE) <= TODAY()-2 and it seems to be working.